# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre por defecto “Seleccionar archivo” a “Selecciona documento” sin usar librerías?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Deseo que no se modifique su estructura, que siga siendo el botón y el tipo `label` donde se muestra el nombre del archivo, solo deseo poder cambiar el nombre del botón.

```html
<input class="form-control" type="file" value="Seleccionar documento">
```

Comment: No, solo deseo cambiar el  nombre del botón

Comment: a que te refieres con nombre del boton ?

Comment: No quiero que esté como Seleccionar archivo, quiero que tenga otro nombre

Answer (score 0):

El selector de archivos que proveen los navegadores no es modificable, una solución común es ocultarlo y generar el propio utilizando un `label`.

```html
<label class="btn" for="myfile">
    Seleccionar documento (version nueva)
</label>
<input type="file" id="myfile" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero ya no quedaría con la misma estructura,  está bien que a partir del label seleccione el documento pero quiero que aparezca el nombre al costado, ¿Cómo podría  hacer eso?

Comment: el FOR del  label apunta hacia el input, asi que cuando le haces click es como si hicieras click en el input. Por lo que no existe problema en eso, usa el label para darle customizacion completa al boton de "Seleccionar"

Answer (score 0):

Como bien a dicho @Diego Andrés el selector no es modificable. +1

Pero, existen pequeños trucos que puedes utilizar para "cambiar el nombre del botón".

```html
<button style="display:block;width:130px; height:30px;" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">MegaSeleccionador</button>
  <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
```

Con `display:none` escondes el input con el nombre que no quieres, (Seleccionar archivo)
Luego creas un botón con el nombre que tu quieras, (Ejemplo: MegaSeleccionador) que al ser clicado llamará al input escondido. El botón lo llamará utilizando un fragmento de Javascript, `document.getElementById('getFile').click()`.

Esta información y código la he seleccionado del SO en inglés, un lugar que te recomiendo conjuntamente con este para encontrar posibles respuestas a tus preguntas, @JuniorXD.

Link de la misma pregunta en el SO inglés.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file